# How to reload angularJs ng-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have an ng-table. I have multiple ng-tables inside one controller. I am giving dynamic attributes i.e. **ng-table="tableParams2" or ng-table="tableParams3"** etc. to them.
I am making an ajax request on button click function to update the data. My http request is being sent at backend. By after I click 3-4 times, I see in console my table is reloaded. By after data, my data remains constant, I don't see the reloaded content in table. Below is my code:

Html:

```
<button ng-click="qualifyX(2)" ></button>

<div class="dragable modal hide fade ui-draggable in" id="ptn_popup" aria-hidden="false" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-original-title="" title="">×</a>
    <h4>Possible matched Companies</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="padding: 10px;">
    <div id="ptn_qualify_res" class="grid-view">
        <div class="summary"></div>
        <table ng-table="tableParams2" show-filter="true" class="items table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr ng-repeat="business in $data">
                <td data-title="'Primary Trading Name'" sortable="'primary_trading_name'" filter="{ 'primary_trading_name': 'text' }">
                    {{business.primary_trading_name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Primary Entity Name'" sortable="'primary_entity_name'" filter="{ 'primary_entity_name': 'text' }">
                    {{business.primary_entity_name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Business Name(s)'" sortable="'business_names'" filter="{ 'business_names': 'text' }">
                    {{business.business_names}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Other Trading Name(s)'" sortable="'other_trading_names'" filter="{ 'other_trading_names': 'text' }">
                    {{business.other_trading_names}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'State'" sortable="'state'" filter="{ 'state': 'text' }">
                    {{business.state}}
                </td>
                <td style="width:70px;">
                    <a data-dismiss="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" data={{business.business_id}} class="ptn_qualify_view_link">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> View &nbsp;</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" id="yw11" href="javascript:void(0);" data-original-title="" title="">Close</a>
</div>
</div>
```

App.js

```
$scope.qualifyX = function(busID) {
    var penModal = $('#popups_container' + busID + ' #pen_popup');
    var pen = $('#popups_container' + busID).next().find('input#Custombusiness_primary_entity_name').val();
    var selectors = {pen: pen, penModal: penModal};
    $http.get(getPtnData + '?ptn=' + selectors.ptn).success(function(data) {
        selectors.ptnModal.find('#ptn_qualify_res').removeClass('grid-view-loading').addClass('grid-view');
        $scope['tableParams' + busID] = new ngTableParams(
                {
                    page: 1, // show first page
                    count: data.length, // count per page
                    sorting:
                            {
                                primary_trading_name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
                            }
                }, {
            total: 0, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                        $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
                        data;
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                        $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                        data;

                params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        }); 
    });
};
```

Create a somewhat similar [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQwNKkMFxCFnzlEzpBEg?p=preview), on every click I want to reload the table with new data.

Comment: Could it be your backend caching the request? I've seen similar behaviour before, and IE is by far the worst, often not even sending a request to the backend

Comment: In my console, I see that request is being sent to backend and the response is new, But when I look at console, I no longer see **ngTable: reload data** message..

Comment: @thsorens: I solved this problem by adding **$scope['tableParams' + busID] = [];** line, before my __$http__ function, which actually clears the data. Now, Only problem left is: ng-table uses $data variable, so when we use say 5 tables inside one controller, we see **ngTable: reload data** message 5 times..

Answer (score 26):

I was having a very similar problem where my table was rendering but not reloading upon an action. What you need to do is to reload $scope.tableParams every time your button is clicked. A simple way to do this is to wrap $scope.tableParams.reload() in a function, and then call that function when the button is clicked.

controller code:

```
$scope.doSearch = function () {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
}
```

html code:

```
<button ng-click="doSearch()">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 12):

I resolved finally the problem.

When I received the update data for the table it's necessary reload the table as follows:

```
$scope.tableData = data;

$scope.tableParams.total($scope.tableData.length);
$scope.tableParams.reload();
```

Answer (score 7):

in case anyone else hits this. I created my own filter that creates a new size array.

I used

`$scope.tableParams.total(data.length)`

to update the length before reloading the table.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me ,
    write it in your function- where you get your dynamic data

```
  $scope.tableParams.reload();
  $scope.tableParams.page(1);
  $scope.tableParams.sorting({});
```